# change webView Font size with Setting Bundle ! [iPhone SDK]

Tags: iphone, sdk

i want change my UIWebView with Setting bundle . what is the property for webview font ?

i know my codes is wrong !

```
if([defaults boolForKey:@"large_font"]) 
    {
        myWeb.font = [ UIFont fontWithName:myGhazal size:32.0f];
    }
    else {

        myWeb.font = [ UIFont fontWithName:myGhazal size:18.0f];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference a css style sheet in your HTML document or put the style information into the top of the HTML document itself.

I think, you cannot set font size by code.

Regards.